# Web Scrape With Multi-Threaded File Downloads from multiple pages Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to web scrape multiple download buttons from multiple pages with the same html tag from this folowing website :

https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2011
https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2012
https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2013

i have tried to web scrape With Multi-Thread but it didnt work. My code is like this

```
import requests
import threading
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os

URLS = [
  'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2011',
  'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2012',
  'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2013',
]

def downloadPage(url, folder):
    os.mkdir(folder) # create folder
    
download_urls = []
filetype = '.csv'

def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for link in get_soup(url).find_all('a'):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    if filetype in file_link:
        #print(file_link)
        download_urls.append(file_link)
        
for file in download_urls: # for each index and file in download_urls
    fileName = file.split('/')[-1] # the text after the last / is the file name we want
    fileRequest = requests.get(file) # download the file
    with open(os.path.join(folder, fileName), 'wb') as examFile: # open a new file in write and binary mode
        examFile.write(fileRequest.content) # write the content of the downloaded file
        
for URL in URLS:
  folderName = URL.split('/')[-1] # the name of the folder
  processThread = threading.Thread(
    target=downloadPage, args=(URL, folderName)) # parameters and functions have to be passed separately
  processThread.start() # start the thread
```

'''

it returns :
NameError: name 'folder' is not defined

Comment: Do you want to download all CSVs from all 3 URLs?

Comment: yes, i want to download all .csv files from every link in the URLS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download all CSVs form the 3 URLs, you can use following example:

```py
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URLS = [
    "https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2011",
    "https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2012",
    "https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2013",
]


for url in URLS:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    folder = url.split("/")[-1]
    os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)

    for a in soup.select('a[href$=".csv"]'):
        file_name = a["href"].split("/")[-1]

        print(
            "Downloading {} ...".format(os.path.join(folder, file_name)),
            end=" ",
        )
        with open(os.path.join(folder, file_name), "wb") as f_out:
            f_out.write(requests.get(a["href"]).content)
        print("OK.")
```

Donwloads the CSVs into 3 folders:

```
indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2011
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Agustus-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-April-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Desember-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Februari-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Januari-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Juli-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Juni-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Maret-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Mei-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-November-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Oktober-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-September-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Agustus-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-April-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Desember-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Februari-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Januari-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Juli-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Juni-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Maret-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Mei-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-November-Tahun-2011.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Oktober-Tahun-2011.csv
└── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-September-Tahun-2011.csv
indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2012
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Agustus-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-April-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Desember-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Februari-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Januari-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Juli-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Juni-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Maret-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Mei-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-November-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Oktober-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-September-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Agustus-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-April-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Desember-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Februari-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Januari-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Juli-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Juni-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Maret-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Mei-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-November-Tahun-2012.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Oktober-Tahun-2012.csv
└── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-September-Tahun-2012.csv
indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2013
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Agustus-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-April-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Desember-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Februari-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Januari-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Juli-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Juni-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Maret-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Mei-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-November-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Oktober-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-September-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Agustus-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-April-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Desember-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Februari-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Januari-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Juli-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Juni-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Maret-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Mei-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-November-Tahun-2013.csv
├── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Oktober-Tahun-2013.csv
└── Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-September-Tahun-2013.csv

0 directories, 72 files
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it works.  even tough without using threading modul, for now its enough for now for me

Comment: the code didnt work for 2019 data, link : https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/data-indeks-standar-pencemar-udara-ispu-di-provinsi-dki-jakarta-tahun-2019 it raise error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data-indeks-standar-pencemar-udara-ispu-di-provinsi-dki-jakarta-tahun-2019\\Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Januari-Tahun-2019.csv'

Answer (score 0):

The error in line 30 is occured because you have never created global variable with named folder. Just include below line somewhere under imports.

```py
url = URLS[0] # select first url
folder = '.' # select working directory as folder
```

Comment: when i add the code, it makes some folders but only download all the csv file from the first url and the csv files is not stored in the newly created folder